# How to fix this merge through terminal

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I pulled an external repo locally to my folder which is connected with `origin master` of my personal repo. The files from the external one got pulled, except the `README.md` and I got an error when I pulled, about a merging error with my local `README.md` file.

Then I did some work, I wanted to push my changes to my repo but got

```
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

I deleted the `readme` file and tried to push again, but same problem. And I don't want to `add --all` to a single commit, because the changes are for different contexts and I want to separate into different commits.

I tried `git checkout --ours README.md` and `--theirs README.md` and then other operations but still no success.

How can I fix this without a UI merging tool, but only through terminal? (I have no unpushed commits locally, atm).

P.S. sorry if I messed up with some terminology - I am just a beginner with git.

**Git status:**

```
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

    new file:   ../bday-picker.js
    new file:   ../bday-picker.min.js
    new file:   ../index.html
    ..other files

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both added:         ../README.md
```

And now I also am thinking why are these 3 `new files` listed , because I deleted them manually through the folder...

Comment: @minitech , awesome! That did the job! You are welcome to post it as an answer, so I can accept it and other ppl can benefit.
@ ComputerDruid, thanks for that suggestion! I also saw many other files that I cleaned up from my working tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git status` shows that you’re already in the middle of a merge; you’ll need to abort that merge before trying again. Run `git merge --abort`, then check `git status` again and clean up anything there, then pull.